# Footer button comes up with soft keyboard in react native modal

Tags: react-native, footer, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a react native app. I am using a fixed footer button which works fine on a page but when it is used inside a modal, it comes on top of soft keyboard when text input gets focussed. I want my footer button to remain fixed at bottom even when the soft keyboard comes up. The structure of my code is:

```
`<Modal>
 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>main</ScrollView>
  <View>footerButton</View>
 </View>
 </Modal>`
```

Below is the code for my footerButton:

```
`<TouchableHighlight 
   style={commonStyles.footerButton} 
   onPress={this.action.bind(this)}>
   <View style={commonStyles.footerbuttonView}>
       <Text style={commonStyles.buttonText}>BUTTON TEXT</Text>
   </View>
 </TouchableHighlight>`

const commonStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  footerButton: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#1a485a',
    position: 'absolute',
    height: height/10,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    margin:0,
    padding:0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
footerbuttonView:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding:15,
  },
buttonText : {
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Light',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 14*fontScale
  },
});
```

I have set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This works fine on all the pages. But on modals it does not work. Can anybody suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: Where you able to figure out what the issue is on this? I am running into a similar problem with adding a footer on a modal.